# How do i find the effective length factor (k) for a column from this chart?

Tags: civil-engineering, design, reinforced-concrete, columns

I need to find the effective length of a column (kl) from this chart which can be found in the "design of concrete structure" By Dr. Arthur Nilson.[image: chart]

the question states "if Psi top is 1.5 and the bottom joint is a firm (fixed) joint what is k? if the column is braced" what I don't know is if the joint is fixed should I take Psi as 0 or infinity? this is a diagram of the column [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take $\psi=0$, typically for fixed braced concrete column, design aids set the bottom as zero flexibility.

Common sense then tells us that if we have a column with top and bottom fixed; it has 2 inflection points at 1/4 length of the column from the bottom and top. Hence we get K= 1/2, which is as shown on this chart.